# Gnosis Safe + Zodiac Module on Polygon - sending assets other than Ethereum

Tags: polygon, gnosis-safe

We are running into an issue with the Zodiac Module with Gnosis Safe integrated in snapshot on Polygon. The Safe contains some test assets (namely MATIC) other than ETH, but in the transaction in snapshot only Ethereum asset transfer is available, and we are not able to choose MATIC or any other asset. Would anyone have an idea of what is happening or what we have initialized incorrectly?
Any assistance would be greatly appreciated!

[image]

EDIT #1:

Thanks Richard.
The safe address is here: 0x46182c824c93E8055b426e5649289706645c0f42

We wanted to transfer arbitrary assets of our own choosing. Can you please elaborate on your comment about the 'native coin'?

Comment: Would you be able to share the Safe address? It might also be that the native coin is always called Ethereum.

Comment: @Richard please see the edit above for clarification. thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The tokens displayed in this drop down are only tokens that are available in the connected Safe.

The Snapshot plugin load the available balances from the Safe service. Therefore only tokens available in the Safe interface will also be available in this dropdown.

Looking at your Safe in the web interface (https://gnosis-safe.io/app/matic:0x46182c824c93E8055b426e5649289706645c0f42/balances) we can see that only Matic is available as an asset. As Matic is the native coin on Polygon the Snapshot interface displays it as "Ethereum" (definitely something that can be improved).